# Symfony Fixtures Loading :Attempted to load class "ClassUtils" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Util"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I am using Symfony7 and PHP 8.2.

I have installed fixtures via `composer` using `composer req orm-fixtures` command.I have created my fixture as well.

When I try to execute this command : `symfony console doctrine:fixtures:load`, I get this error :

```
In BroadcastListener.php line 138:
                                                                               
Attempted to load class "ClassUtils" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Util".  
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I have tried reverting `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle` to older version, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, it seems there is a missing dependency in `symfony/ux-turbo` on `BroadcastListener` class.

You can remove ux-turbo, if you don't need it : `composer remove symfony/ux-turbo`

Or add the missing dependency : `composer require doctrine/common`

Comment: add the missing dependency : composer require doctrine/common - worked for me